# Adding additonal NIC on guest VM - linux KVM

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

How to add additional NIC to guest VM machine, on linux KVM using virt-manager

Comment: if you dont have any way to alter the vm, maybe you're in virt-viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `vitr-manager` open the guest window and on topbar is lightbulb icon. In this window you can add hardware. 
Some hardware can be added only vhen guest is poweroff or need restart after change

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this question is a great fit for SF, in part because I am not sure the situation you describe fits within the [topics you can ask about here](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

It isn't clear from your question if you have the required rights to do what you are trying to do - are you the VM administrator, and are you able to configure/modify any parts of the setup?

You may find some use in looking into [virsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/virsh), notably its `iface-*` operations.
Alternatively, if you are comfortable with `vi` and XML, you can `virsh edit` your guest to add a NIC.

The fact you have no options to edit your guest via virt-manager would however suggest you may not have enough access/rights to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have **root** access and i want to add additional NIC to configure **teaming**, but i am unable to find any option on **virt-manager**, even when the guest is **power-off** there is no option to edit the config

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cloudstack, you can do this easily.
Cloudstack has option to choose particular bridge for guest traffic.

If you are not using Cloudstack, create another bridge with new nic and edit the xml file directly and replace the existing bridge in configuration file with new bridge.

Answer (score 0):

I found options in the guest panel under view options **console** and **details** where i can edit details in details option

Comment: If this question is solved, please mark it as solved by ticking the check mark next to the answer. Thank you!